# Why is día plural in this phrase?

Tags: gramática, plurales

I notice that at the foot of a certificate which I have it states:

> En Caracas, a los 10 días del mes de Octubre de 2009

Since the certificate was issued in Venezuela by a university I assume it must be grammatical but why is día plural here when there was clearly only one day 10/10/2009?

Just to clarify, I have quoted exactly what is says on the certificate. I am sure the month is written with an initial capital even though it is in a blackletter font (Escritura gótica)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other answers that the period elapsed justifies the use of the plural.

The structure:

- **a X días** de mes Y de año Z
- **a los X días** de mes Y de año Z

is typical of formal, mainly legal documents.

The grammatical reason why the plural is used is that a plural noun is needed after a cardinal number, as is the case with "10" (10 días).

Instead, if a cardinal number (e.g. 10) is found after the noun or an ordinal number (e.g. 10º) is found before the noun, the noun will be in singular form because the number will not quantify (i.e. express the number of days) but instead specify the day in question:

- **el Xº día** de mes Y de año Z
- **el día X** de mes Y de año Z

We can thus have:

- En Caracas, el (día) 10 de(l mes de) octubre de(l año) 2009
- En Caracas, el 10º día de(l mes de) octubre de(l año) 2009
- En Caracas, a (los) 10 días de(l mes de) octubre de(l año) 2009

Important note 1: In Spanish, months are NOT capitalized.

Important note 2: In Spanish, we don't use the preposition "en" but only the article to introduce a date.

Comment: a los 10 días del mes de Octubre de 2009 ,me parece muy estraño.

Comment: Es de uso corriente en documentos legales.

Comment: No en los que yo he traducido.  el 10º día del mes de octubre, si.

Comment: Sobran ejemplos en Internet. Basta con buscar: En X ciudad, a los X días del mes de ... y aparecerán decenas de casos. Este es solo uno de los tantos que aparecen: https://madrid.consulado.gov.co/sites/default/files/Acto%20Administrativo%2011%20de%2010%20de%20junio%202022.pdf (En página 10 dice: Dado en Madrid, a los 10 días del mes de junio de 2022.)

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not referring to the tenth day, even though it is coincidental, but it's talking about the days of the month that have elapsed until the certificate is obtained. In other words:

> En Caracas, al haber transcurrido 10 días del mes de Octubre de 2009

It would be different if it's the tenth day:

> En Caracas, en el día 10 del mes de Octubre de 2009

> En Caracas, en el décimo día del mes de Octubre de 2009

Answer (score -1):

Día 10/10/2009

> En Caracas, a los 10 días del mes de Octubre de 2009

La oración remite a los "**días**" que han ido pasando o sucediéndose desde que comenzó el mes de Octubre. No esta diciendo, hoy "**Día** 10 de Octubre del año 2009", sino que indica los días que han avanzado o corrido desde el inicio del mes. Por esa razón se utiliza el plural "Días" en lugar de "Día".

**P.D.** Una forma curiosa de referirse a la fecha, aunque un tanto anticuada.

> The prayer refers to the "** días **" that have been passing or
> succeeding each other since the month of October began. It is not
> saying, today "**Día** October 10 of the year 2009", but it indicates
> the days that have advanced or run since the beginning of the month.
> For that reason the plural "Days" is used instead of "Day".
>
> **P.S.** A curious way of referring to the date, although a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido le ves a duplicar respuestas?

Comment: Referirse a los días del mes que han transcurrido hasta obtener el certificado, es ambiguo. ¿ No te parece? Los días transcurren "en el mes", independientemente de que sea un certificado u otro el motivo.

Comment: Pues esto es un comentario a la repuesta ya formulada, no hay necesidad de repetir exactamente lo mismo que ya ha sido respondido. Es ruido y no aclara nada.

Comment: @Diego por tu comentario, parece que te has basado en [la respuesta de Danielillo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42163/24236) al escribir la tuya. Si escribes respuestas basadas en otras fuentes (ya sean otras respuestas de Stack Exchange u otros sitios), debes citar las fuentes. El plagio [no está permitido](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) en Stack Exchange. Tu respuesta debe además añadir algo nuevo que no esté en las otras respuestas: la traducción al español de una respuesta en inglés es válida, pero la cita debe estar incluida.